# Excel with C# connection

Tags: c#, excel

I have this code

```
exapplication = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook WB = exapplication.ThisWorkbook;
WB.Connections.AddFromFile("C:\test.odc");
```

and when I trying to compile it, it gives me the following exception:

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
```

Comment: Your string literal doesn't escape the backslash character - is this a typo, or could that be your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should replace

```
WB.Connections.AddFromFile("C:\test.odc");
```

by

```
WB.Connections.AddFromFile(@"C:\test.odc");
```

although I don't really think that exception is because of this.

Comment: Or without the literal, escape like this:  WB.Connections.AddFromFile("C:\\test.odc");